# sbt-assembly not found when building Spark 0.5

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I am trying to build the 0.5 branch of Spark, but it raises errors:

> sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.8.3: not found

Hence, I download the `ivys` and `jars` manually from [dl.bintray.com](http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.9.1/sbt_0.11.3/0.8.3/), and put them into my local `.ivy` folder.

To be specific, I create a `sbt-assembly` under `com.eed3si9n`, and I rename files as:

[image]

However, this does not work. What is the correct solution?

Comment: I'm curious why you need such an old Spark version?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski bcz I am trying to fully understand its source code, and the 0.5 brach is in its initial form. Hence, I think it is a good start from it.

Comment: Have fun! I'm a bit doubtful about the results. I'd rather start with the latest and greatest even though the codebase could be overwhelming. The base has not changed that much (and even if it did, it's more worthwhile to know how things are now not back then, isn't it?). Ping me offline to discuss it.

Answer (score 4):

Spark `branch-0.5` uses sbt 0.11.3 according to [`project/build.properties`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-0.5/project/build.properties), so that's pretty old.

#### sbt community repository location

There's a bug in `project/plugins.sbt`. It's pointing to `scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com`, but it should point to `repo.scala-sbt.org`.

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/project/plugins.sbt b/project/plugins.sbt
index 63d789d0c1..70dcfdba00 100644
--- a/project/plugins.sbt
+++ b/project/plugins.sbt
@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
 resolvers ++= Seq(
   "sbt-idea-repo" at "http://mpeltonen.github.com/maven/",
   Classpaths.typesafeResolver,
-  Resolver.url("sbt-plugin-releases", new URL("http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
+  Resolver.url("sbt-plugin-releases", new URL("http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
 )
```

#### JDK 1.6

To run older version of sbt, it's necessary to use older JDK. In this case, JDK 1.6. On macOS, however, there's an issue with JLine with JDK 1.6, so I had to disable JLine.

```
$ jenv shell 1.6
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
...
$ sbt/sbt -Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal
```

This should get the sbt shell started. Once it comes up, type in:

```
> package
```

Comment: Thanks. Since the source code of 0.5 branch is in a much smaller scale, I think it is good to read the source code based that branch. BTW, how can I determine the correct `JDK` version for different version of `Spark`? does it mainly depend on the `Scala` version used?

Comment: Basically. You can sort of guess the stable JDK version based on the date. JDK 1.7 came out in 2011 so maybe it works too, but JDK 1.6 would be a safer bet.